# Creat a uniformly distributed random variable by Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a random variable that takes a value in set {-2, -1, 1, 2} with probability p = 0.25. How can I do it in Matlab ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [randi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html). If you just want a single value:

```
>> x = [-2, -1, 1, 2];
>> random_var = x(randi(length(x)))
random_var =
     2
```

If you want more than one:

```
>> random_vars = x(randi(length(x), 3, 10))
random_vars =
     2    -1     2     2    -2     2    -2     1    -1     1
     1     1    -2    -1    -1     2     2     2     1    -2
    -2     2     2     2     2     1     2     1    -2    -1
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want.